# Error running GWT Codeserver in Github Codespaces

Tags: java, maven, github, gwt

I'm able to compile my GWT app (*and run GWT Codeserver*) in Github Codespaces with this
`mvn gwt:codeserver -f "/workspaces/myapp/app-client/pom.xml" -am`

However when this command is used: (*the same command works in my local machine, same project*)
`mvn gwt:codeserver -pl app-client -am`

It throws

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.940 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-20T02:19:42Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.executeForkedExecutions (MojoExecutor.java:439)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] 
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory
```

I'm wondering what could be causing the error. It seems to be rooted here: https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/e2a8db3f0285e8853bb97e1864edb3c1e5143dc6/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/MojoExecutor.java#L439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this might be a bug (or change in behavior) in Maven 3.9.0, which appears to be the default install for codespaces. Here's a quick workaround:

1. Using the maven wrapper plugin, install an older maven version (which will be run using the `./mvnw` script, that the plugin will also install for you:

   ```bash
      mvn wrapper:wrapper -Dmaven=3.8.7
   ```
2. Run your command again, but using the `./mvnw` wrapper instead of the `mvn` binary on your PATH:

   ```bash
      ./mvnw gwt:codeserver -f "/workspaces/myapp/app-client/pom.xml" -am
   ```

I spent a few minutes looking for a bug report in the Maven JIRA, but didn't immediately see one that matches this description, it might be worth your time to file it.

Comment: Thanks, Colin. Btw, is there a way to change the behavior of how SDM is loaded? The proxying of ports in Codespaces prevents SDM from being loaded: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75505269/how-to-change-the-behavior-of-superdevmode-to-make-it-run-on-github-codespaces